# Why are my floating labels not working in my Laravel project with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

## Issue with Bootstrap floating labels not working in Laravel project

I am currently working on a Laravel project and trying to implement floating labels in a form using Bootstrap. However, I am encountering an issue where the floating labels are not functioning as expected. I have followed the Bootstrap documentation and added the necessary classes, but the labels remain static and do not float when the input fields are focused or filled.

```
<section class="h-100 gradient-form" style="background-color: #eee;">
  <div class="container py-5 h-100">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-xl-10">
        <div class="card rounded-3 text-black">
          <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="card-body p-md-5 mx-md-4">

                <div class="text-center">
                  <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-login-form/lotus.webp"
                    style="width: 185px;" alt="logo">
                  <h4 class="mt-1 mb-5 pb-1">We are The Lotus Team</h4>
                </div>

                <form>
                  <p>Please login to your account</p>

                  <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                    <input type="email" id="form2Example11" class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Phone number or email address" />
                    <label class="form-label" for="form2Example11">Username</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                    <input type="password" id="form2Example22" class="form-control" />
                    <label class="form-label" for="form2Example22">Password</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="text-center pt-1 mb-5 pb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block fa-lg gradient-custom-2 mb-3" type="button">Log
                      in</button>
                    <a class="text-muted" href="#!">Forgot password?</a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pb-4">
                    <p class="mb-0 me-2">Don't have an account?</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Create new</button>
                  </div>

                </form>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-center gradient-custom-2">
              <div class="text-white px-3 py-4 p-md-5 mx-md-4">
                <h4 class="mb-4">We are more than just a company</h4>
                <p class="small mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                  exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have copied and pasted the provided code into my Laravel project. However, after doing so, the floating labels are still not functioning as expected

[My project on laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt9qP.png)

Comment: Can you post file where you have included bootstrap?

Comment: Not even the example under https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/floating-labels/ is working for me, so perhaps not a fault of your code to begin with, but something broken in BS, I suppose?

Comment: @CBroe That example works (for me, Firefox) if you type something into the input fields

Comment: Yes, you're right, my bad - I expected the labels to float as soon as the input field gets focussed, but it does work when I type into it.